# Best 3rd party RAM for MacBook Pros?

Tags: upgrade, memory

I recently bought a 15" MacBook Pro (Late 2011) with 4GB of RAM. I want to upgrade to 8GB, but I've read that MacBooks can be kind of picky when it comes to RAM and will not operate right if it is given low quality RAM. So, barring RAM that you buy from Apple (Which is $400 for 8GB of RAM), what is the best RAM I can get for performance and price?

Comment: I'm sorry, but shopping and buying recommendations are off topic as per the [faq](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like thats the same RAM as in my 13" Macbook Pro (Late 2011) 204-pin PC-10600 (1333 MHz) DDR3 SO-DIMM? If so, I recently picked up 8GB (2 x 4GB kit) from [Crucial UK](http://www.crucial.com/uk) for £35. There is also [Crucial US](http://www.crucial.com/) and the same kit looks to be $46 as far as I can tell. All seems fine and it's working perfectly as I type this! I've always bought my Mac RAM from Crucial without any problems.